# pass value of clicked list to EditForm to edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am doing reactjs and redux for developing dashboard. I have done add, delete but editing is not working. When user clicks on item, the textfield should display with its current value and able to submit the changes. I can show textfield when clicked but could not show the current value of that item which is clicked. To display textField i have to use onClick on the li tag otherwise i could pass data like using this.props.editTab(tab). How can i now send data of clicked item to editTab action ?

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { open: false, editing: false };
}

editTab() {
  const tabs = _.map(this.props.tabs, (tab) => {
      if (tab.editable) {
        return (
            <li
              className="list-group-items delete-tab-list"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ editing: true })}
              key={tab.id}
            >
              <i className="material-icons">{tab.icon}</i>{tab.name}
            </li>
        );
      }
  });
  return (
      <div className="device-action">
        <Dialog
            title="Update a Tab"
            modal={false}
            bodyStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            contentStyle={customContentStyle}
            actionsContainerStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            titleStyle={{ background: '#fff', color: '#1ab394' }}
            open={this.props.createTab.open}
            onRequestClose={this.props.closeTabIcon}
        >
          <ul className="list-group">
            { this.state.editing ?
                  <EditForm
                      tab={this.props.tabs}
                      editing={this.state.editing}
                  /> :
                 tabs
             }
          </ul>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
}


handleEditSave = (name, icon) => {
    this.props.editTab(name, icon);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleEditSave}>
        <div className="tab-name">
          <TextField
            floatingLabelText="Name"
            onChange={(name) => { this.setState({ name: name.target.value }); }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
          <AutoComplete
            floatingLabelText="select any icon"
            filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
            openOnFocus
            onNewRequest={(e) => { this.setState({ icon: e.id }); }}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="btn">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

How can i pass clicked item data to EditForm component so i can trigger my action in this.props.editTab(tab) this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply track the tab you editing by saving it on the state.
This will work only if you want to edit 1 tab at time. otherwise you can use Object/Array.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { open: false, editing: null };
}

editTab() {
  const tabs = _.map(this.props.tabs, (tab) => {
      if (tab.editable) {
        return (
            <li
              className="list-group-items delete-tab-list"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ editing: tab })}
              key={tab.id}
            >
              <i className="material-icons">{tab.icon}</i>{tab.name}
            </li>
        );
      }
  });

  const { editing } = this.state;

  // editing is the Tab object that we edit
  if (editing)
    console.log("Editing tab: " + editable.name);

  return (
      <div className="device-action">
        <Dialog
            title="Update a Tab"
            modal={false}
            bodyStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            contentStyle={customContentStyle}
            actionsContainerStyle={{ background: '#fff' }}
            titleStyle={{ background: '#fff', color: '#1ab394' }}
            open={this.props.createTab.open}
            onRequestClose={this.props.closeTabIcon}
        >
          <ul className="list-group">
            { this.state.editing ?
                  <EditForm
                      tab={this.props.tabs}
                      editing={this.state.editing}
                  /> :
                 tabs
             }
          </ul>
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
}


handleEditSave = (name, icon) => {
    this.props.editTab(name, icon);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleEditSave}>
        <div className="tab-name">
          <TextField
            floatingLabelText="Name"
            onChange={(name) => { this.setState({ name: name.target.value }); }}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="icon">
          <AutoComplete
            floatingLabelText="select any icon"
            filter={AutoComplete.noFilter}
            openOnFocus
            onNewRequest={(e) => { this.setState({ icon: e.id }); }}
          />
        </div>
        <button className="btn">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Otherwise you have to use object/array means i have to use editing:[ ]? This solutions works but when i click on item other item disappears. I can only edit one at a time like you have said.

Comment: Yeah, turning `editing` into object/array and then loop the tabs you need to edit.

Comment: Can you help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40079744/submit-form-data-in-each-step ?